# java 8 javafx getBehavior() alternative?

Tags: java, javafx-8, java-8

```
    SkinBase skin = (SkinBase) tabPane.getSkin();
    TabPaneBehavior tabPaneBehavior = (TabPaneBehavior) skin.getBehavior();
    tabPaneBehavior.selectNextTab();
```

There is no such method in Java 8, how can I get behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
TabPaneSkin skin = (TabPaneSkin) tabPane.getSkin();
//or BehaviorSkinBase skin = (BehaviorSkinBase) tabPane.getSkin();
TabPaneBehavior tabPaneBehavior = (TabPaneBehavior) skin.getBehavior();
tabPaneBehavior.selectNextTab();
```